# How to find the server provided MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS value?

Tags: java, http, http2

I am using [java.net.http](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.net.http/module-summary.html) to make some http calls to a server. However, sometimes I get a "too many concurrent streams" exception from here: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.net.http/share/classes/jdk/internal/net/http/Http2Connection.java#L440.

It appears my client is exceeding the `MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS` value that the server has set. From other sources, it sounds like I need to set up a semaphore to ensure I don't exceed that value.

The problem is that I have no idea what the server's value for `MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS` is. It doesn't appear to be accessible via the java.net.http API.

Anyone know how I can figure out the `MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS` the server is setting?

Comment: It sounds like you are leaking connections instead.  Make sure you clean up each connection when done, and keep track of the high watermark. When you get the exception, that will tell you what the server's maximum is.

Comment: I'm no expert, but that looks like a value set in your client library, not your server. I followed back to this [this constant](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.net.http/share/classes/jdk/internal/net/http/frame/SettingsFrame.java#L69C29-L69C58).

Comment: @BasilBourque nope, it has a default value of Integer.MAX_VALUE set by the client but once a connection is made the server will change that value.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `java.net.http.HttpClient` does not expose the value for `MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS` sent by the server.

You may try and guess it and then use a `Semaphore` to avoid exceeding it, but that is a lot of work you should not be doing as a user of `java.net.http.HttpClient`.

[Disclaimer: I am a Jetty maintainer.]

You can switch and use Jetty's `HttpClient`, which does not suffer from this problem, as it carefully handles the `MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS` value, allowing that many concurrent requests per connection, and if that value is exceeded, opens a new connection for the excess concurrent requests.

Jetty's `HttpClient` also offers many more features and configuration options than JDK's `HttpClient`, so the switch may help you in other ways.

You can find the documentation about Jetty's `HttpClient` here:
https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/programming-guide/index.html#pg-client-http